# Tab Activity: Some space at the top of tab content

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have created my own custom TabActivity. The problem is that each page leaves a small blank strip at the top and the bottom of the tab content. My tab layouts try to fill the parent but still some strips are visible.

[image: screen]

the blue lower strip should touch upper strip.

my tab activity xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navigation_bar"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRecipesChosen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navigatorBarLeftRightButtonsMargin"
            android:background="@drawable/button_chosen" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRecipesFind"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/navigatorBarLeftRightButtonsMargin"
            android:background="@drawable/button_find" >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_marginBottom="-9dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late for the answer but i had kind of the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434027/android-tabwidget-white-space-issue) so this might help for others searching out solution for the same issue ... Try out the drawable xml files in [this](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android) project and try to replace the layout xml file of tab xml like it's done in [this](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android) project [here](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android) .. Hope it works !!