# Android TabWidget White Space Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, android-widget

I am working on the TabWidget and i am getting a white space between the TabActivity and the Tabs.

I don't know how to remove this white space please can any one help me out how should i remove it, my tab_main.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I tried to put background color of TabWidget to android:color:transparent but still same white space comes between the Activity and the Tab.

I do not want any separation space between my Activity and the Tabs (Is it possible to do it?)

Please can any one suggest me how to get rid of this white space.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to make the height of the `TabWidget` to 0dp similar to the frame layout? Also, if you are targeting API 8 or more you should use `match_parent` instead of fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Look's Like you are having similar issue as i was having in my project, check out [this](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android) project and try to implement the drawable xml files and provide your TabWidget with the specific custom dimensions as given in this project. It will surely work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The output you've shown most likely suggests a Margin/Padding error, rather than a layout error. Either your `TabWidget` or your `FrameLayout` could have a margin getting inherited by the overall theme that you're using.

Most likely the following will fix the problem (note the extra margin/padding styles):

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
            android:layout_paddingBottom="0dip"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            ....
            .... />

        <TabWidget
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_paddingTop="0dip"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            ....
            .... />
```

Your FrameLayout could also have any nested components which have a margin/padding, and which in turn may cause the white space. I've added the `android:background` to both the FrameLayout and the TabWidget, just to help troubleshoot if there is any white space in between.

You said that you've tried putting background color of the TabWidget to transparent - but it won't help, because if there is a margin - then the underlying activity's background color shows up as white, below the transparent area. If you set the overall `RelativeLayout`'s background color to something like blue - then you will see the blue coming through. So fix the margin/padding rather than trying to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

From your screen shot, it looks like you are using a `WebView`. `Webview` comes with a default `margin` and `padding` > 0. You can set the `padding` and `margin` to zero by overriding the `WebView's` `body` tag, or using `css`.

For further details, please see the answers to the following SO question:

[Remove unwanted white space in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694184/remove-unwanted-white-space-in-webview-android)